# How to force applications to not use VPN on Windows 7

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I'm running OpenVPN on Windows 7 and using Comodo Firewall to allow 1 specific application to only use the VPN (preventing that application from accessing the Internet if the VPN goes down). I have only 1 network adapter.

This works fine but all my other applications are also going over the VPN even though I've set the VPN's gateway to a higher metric. I have tried telling Comodo to block all other applications from using the VPN but then none of them can access the Internet at all.

My VPN rules are based on MAC address, telling that one app to only use the VPN's MAC address and telling all other apps to use only the MAC address of my network adapter (I also tried telling them to use any MAC address other than the VPN). I played around with ForceBindIP a while back with no success.

I don't understand why traffic prefers the VPN even when its metric is higher and why everything stops working if I block access to the VPN, why can't I send traffic outside the VPN?

Note: I run VMWare on the same machine and it uses the network adapter normally even when the VPN is running.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue a while back by following [these](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway) steps to have all applications ignore the VPN by default, and then binding only one application (in my case Chrome) to the VPN using ForceBindIP.

The issue with here is that you will always need to start that application through ForceBindIP. And should your VPN ever lose its connection, it'll switch back to the default network again, requiring a restart to go back to the VPN.

This wasn't a problem for me, since I'm only using it for my browser. Your situation might be different.